# Unity Jar Resolver Replaces Conflicting Dependencies With Versions That Do Not Exist

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working in Unity and have been trying to get Google Services, Firebase, Crashlytics, and Jar Resolver to play nice without success. As far as I can tell, everything is in the right place. The problem shows up when Jar Resolver tries to do its thing. It comes across some conflicting dependencies and changes them. However, it is setting many of them to versions that do not exist. Or, I have yet to find version 16.1.1 of play-services-base...

How do I stop Jar Resolver from modifying dependencies and resolve the conflict myself?

I am running Mac OS, Unity 2018.1.4f1, and Jar Resolver 1.2.75.0.

[Image: Jar Resolver dependency conflict resolution gone wrong.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7wwP.png)

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-base?repo=google The resolver just uses the data given to it. You may need to edit the dependency vales to force it to the correct version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retired Ninja was right, I had to go in and modify the dependency values to force the correct version. Firebase has two dependency files that were causing the problem:

- Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml
- Assets/Firebase/Editor/AnalyticsDependencies.xml

I changed the "16.0.0" and "16.0.1" version numbers to "11.8.0" in both files and Jar Resolver was able to complete successfully. This will probably cause other issues, but that is a different issue to be resolved later.